# Simple Exercise with the Distribution Function (Proof Critique)

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, fourier-analysis

I want to prove that If $\left| f \right| \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \left| f_n \right|$ $\mu$-a.e., then $d_f \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} d_{f_n}$.

Here is my estimate \begin{eqnarray*}
d_f(\alpha) &=& \mu (\{ x \in X \ : \ \left| f(x) \right| > \alpha \}) \\
& \leq & \mu \left( \bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{n=m}^{\infty} \{ x \in X \ : \ \left| f_n(x) \right| > \alpha \} \right) \\
& \leq & \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \mu \left( \bigcap_{n=m}^{\infty} \{ x \in X \ : \ \left| f_n(x) \right| > \alpha \} \right) \\
& \leq & \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \liminf_{n \to \infty} \mu \left( \{ x \in X \ : \ \left| f_n(x) \right| > \alpha \} \right) \\
&=& \liminf_{n \to \infty} \mu (\{ x \in X \ : \ \left| f_n(x) \right| > \alpha \}) \ \ \ \ \ \ (\star)\\
&=& \liminf_{n \to \infty} d_{f_n}(\alpha).
\end{eqnarray*}

My only worry is in the deduction to line $(\star)$, my justification was there was no dependence on $m$ in the argument and therefore the summation can be removed. Is this justified?

Answer (score 0):

(*)is wrong. You are summing over $m$ infinitely many positive numbers so you get $\infty$.
Prove it as follows

1. Prove that if $f\le g$ then $d_f(\alpha)\le d_g(\alpha)$
2. Prove that if $g_n\le g_{n+1}$ then $d_g(\alpha)=\lim_n d_{g_n}(\alpha)$
3. Apply 2 to $g_n=\inf_{m\ge n}f_m$